# how to filter nested object in es6 and return the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an object that contains nested objects. i would like to filter through them and return the key if present.

for example:

```
var meals = {
    food_meals: [
      {meal_id: 15749, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},
      {meal_id: 15750, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true}
    ],
    wine_meals: [
      {meal_id: 11651, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},
      {meal_id: 4424, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true}
    ],
    kids_meals: [
      {meal_id: 15763, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},
      {meal_id: 15764, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},
      {meal_id: 15765, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true}
    ]
}
```

If i had a meal with `meal_id` of 15764 then I would want the key of that value returned (in this case `kids_meals`)

i can filter the meal from the nested object by doing

```
meals.kids_meals.filter(meal => meal.meal_id == this.props.selection.meal_id)
```

where `this.props.selection.meal_id` is 15764

my desired output is 'kids_meals' in this case, but i can't seem to reach it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over the `Object.entries` of the `meals` to get an array of key-value pairs, and use `.find` on that array to get the key-value pair whose value is an array that contains the matching `meal_id`:

```js
const meals = {
    food_meals: [
      {meal_id: 15749, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},
      {meal_id: 15750, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true}
    ],
    wine_meals: [
      {meal_id: 11651, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},
      {meal_id: 4424, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true}
    ],
    kids_meals: [
      {meal_id: 15763, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},
      {meal_id: 15764, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},
      {meal_id: 15765, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true}
    ]
};

const idToFind = 15764;
const foundEntry = Object.entries(meals)
  .find(
    ([, arr]) => arr.some(
      ({ meal_id }) => meal_id === idToFind
    )
  );
if (foundEntry) {
  console.log(foundEntry[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `filter` is for creating a new array with objects which meet a specific condition.  In this case, you need to use the function `find` to extract an object which meets a condition.

This alternative uses the function `find` along with the function `some` to find at least one object with a specific `meal_id`.

```js
let meals = {    food_meals: [      {meal_id: 15749, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},      {meal_id: 15750, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true}    ],    wine_meals: [      {meal_id: 11651, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},      {meal_id: 4424, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true}    ],    kids_meals: [      {meal_id: 15763, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},      {meal_id: 15764, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},      {meal_id: 15765, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true}    ]},
    target = 15764,
    found = Object.keys(meals).find(k => meals[k].some(({meal_id}) => meal_id === target));

console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Array#filter , Array#findIndex and Object.keys

```js
const data={food_meals:[{meal_id:15749,address_required:!1,button_text:"choose",can_choose_meal:!0},{meal_id:15750,address_required:!1,button_text:"choose",can_choose_meal:!0}],wine_meals:[{meal_id:11651,address_required:!1,button_text:"choose",can_choose_meal:!0},{meal_id:4424,address_required:!1,button_text:"choose",can_choose_meal:!0}],kids_meals:[{meal_id:15763,address_required:!1,button_text:"choose",can_choose_meal:!0},{meal_id:15764,address_required:!1,button_text:"choose",can_choose_meal:!0},{meal_id:15765,address_required:!1,button_text:"choose",can_choose_meal:!0}]}

const id = 15764;

const res = Object.keys(data).filter(key=>{
  return data[key].findIndex(({meal_id})=>meal_id===id) > -1
}).join("");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is relatively close to @CertainPerformance 's answer, and I don't mean to say that his is invalid at all, however, you might find that this is a bit easier to read, and secondly if there's ever a meal that is available in more than one category( a use case that you may not have thought of ), it'll return an array.

```
Object.keys(meals).filter(type => meals[type].some(item => item.meal_id === idToFind));
```

```js
var meals = {
    food_meals: [
      {meal_id: 15749, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},
      {meal_id: 15750, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true}
    ],
    wine_meals: [
      {meal_id: 11651, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},
      {meal_id: 4424, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true}
    ],
    kids_meals: [
      {meal_id: 15763, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},
      {meal_id: 15764, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true},
      {meal_id: 15765, address_required: false, button_text: "choose", can_choose_meal: true}
    ]
}
let r = Object.keys(meals).filter(type => meals[type].some(item => item.meal_id === 15749));

console.log(r);
```